# Making input form boxes horizontal in HTML

Tags: html

I been doing some html code in a few days now, but i can't figure out how to make the it all in a horizontal look, just like this exsampel:

```
ID     Name     Commodity    Weight    Tolerance
Box     Box      drop down    box          box
```

So box stands for "input form" ofc, and a drop down should be full of names of commodities from my database.

**Right now, i have this code so far:**

```
<body>

<div id="header">
    <h2 align="center" style="color: #FFFFFF">Edit Recept</h2>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="form-wrapper">
        <form method="post" action="Front">

        <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>ID: <td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="Id" />
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Name:<td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" />
                </tr>

        </table>

        <table>
                <tr>

                <p>     </p>
                <p>Add commodities to your recept: <p>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td>Select commodity:<td>
                    <td><select>
                            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select Commodity</option>
                            <option value="1">One</option>
                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                        </select>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>Weight:<td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="tolerance" />
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Tolerance:<td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" />
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Add" /><td> 
                <tr>    
        </table>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
                <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
                <input type="hidden" name="whichPage" value="prescription"/>


        </form>

    </div>
    <p align="center">
        Enter the new values and press save to make the change 
    </p>
</div>
```

Is there a trick how to do it easy?? My goal is to make it like i described on the top, and then add a button which will add a new line of input boxes under the other if you want to store more commodities in the same prescription.

Comment: looks like you haven't tried anything at all regarding the button. do some research and try something on your own… a simple google search will give you thousands of examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your labels all in one single row of the table, then the input fields for those labels should be jsut under in a second row. So you will have a colomn based input just as you wish, here is [a fiddle as a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/tmarwen/WVrS8/).

```
<div id="header">
  <h2 align="center" style="color: #FFFFFF">Edit Recept</h2>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="form-wrapper">
  <form method="post" action="Front">

    <table>

      <tr>
        <td>ID </td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Select commodity</td>
        <td>Weight</td>
        <td>Tolerance</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="Id" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
        <td><select>
          <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select Commodity</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tolerance" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
    <input type="hidden" name="whichPage" value="prescription"/>
  </form>

</div>
<p align="center">
  Enter the new values and press save to make the change
</p>
</div>
```

**Note:** You should pay attention to the closing tags for table element markups as you are missing some and introducing an open tag instead of a closing one in some rows.

Comment: Thats awesome, this looks cool.

Lets say a user want to add more commodities to the prescription like i said, i'm going to make another button like "New Commodity" or something like that.

Then it should open op 5 more input boxes below the others, where the user can select a new one before saving. 

Is there an easy way to do this? maybe if i turn it to a jsp file?

Comment: You can handle that with sample JavaScript code. You should first try something on you own then you are always welcome and you can give a sign to the topic link and I will delighted to help you. By now you can accept the answer or upvote it if you are satisfied with :)

Comment: Yes ofcause, i try make something cool out of this :) thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small hint. This will show the text and input box below each other. But you need to rearrange your whole table with the proper manner. Also dont use multiple tables. Use single table with many columns.

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>ID: </td> 
       <td>Name:</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="Id" /></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How do you get name to stand like the ID, under the box for the name?
if you look, name is to much to the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/pixeldk/TFPX2/

Comment: sorry it was a typo in my answer. I have updated my code. check it out now.

Comment: You was writing `<td>` instead of `</td>` in your sample, here you have it wirtten with correct end tags so the output will just fit in what you are expecting, http://jsfiddle.net/tmarwen/TFPX2/1/