# Add button in jsp which will change something in the same page

Tags: html, jsp

my question is how to make a button in a html or jsp page which when clicked on will add something to the same page.

So if i got a jsp page called Prescription.jsp, and i got some input forms like:

```
ID     name   select commodity   weight   tolerance
box     box       drop down        box       box
```

Where box = inputs in a input form. an example you see under here.

[image]

I want the page to show only 1 input form of Id, name, commodity, weight and tolerance when the page is loaded, and if you click on "Add Commodity" in the top corner, you should add a new set of boxes under.

I don't know if this is possible, because i'm not sure where to look for the right answer.

Comment: "I don't know if this is possible, because i'm not sure where to look for the right answer" did you at least try a [google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+add+form+control+on+click+of+a+button+using+javascript&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=GimYU7qNLKTV8ge8wICwBg&gws_rd=ssl#q=how+to+add+form+elements+on+click+of+a+button+using+javascript&rls=en&safe=active)..? why are you consecutively posting questions in SO without even trying anything..? [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making input form boxes horizontal in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157726/making-input-form-boxes-horizontal-in-html)

Comment: Have tried, all i find is using java script, I'm not supposed to use java script for this project, because we haven't had any lecture about it.

Must be a way with java in jsp or something?

Comment: If you want to manipulate something in client side, you need client side script. other wise you need to send a request to server and have the jsp re-rendered. which is not the way to do it, which is probably why you didn't find anything...

Comment: So you saying i have to make this with script, if it should work well?

Comment: Well it's easy. why go all the way around your head to touch your nose when you can do it directly.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#addCommodity").click(function(){                   

              $("#commdity-table tr:last").clone().find('input').val('').end().insertAfter("#commdity-table tr:last");

            });
        });
    </script>
```

---

```
 <table id="commdity-table">

 ....

 </table>
 <input type="button" value="Add Commodity" id="addCommodity" />
```

Comment: It works so far. One question, if i add a new commodity using the button you made, how do i know what parameter names they have?

Like the first input field for Id, it has name=id1 <td><input type="text" name="id1" /></td> 

what is the name for the other id's??

Comment: Name will be same (You can see by R. Click->Inspect Element). You have to use String[] ids = request.getParameterValues("id1");